# OSX Safari applying media query 15 pixels early

Tags: css, safari, media-queries

I have 2 media query sizes -

`only screen and (min-width: 980px)and (max-width: 1499px)";`

`only screen and (min-width: 768px)and (max-width: 979px)";`

Safari is applying the second media query while the browser width is still in range of the first one - when the window.innerwidth is between 980 - 995.

I've never seen this before - any ideas?

**update -**

so I figured out the issue - the new OSX safari's media queries use *document.documentElement.clientWidth* as a measurement - while all other browsers (and what i've coded for to have javascript kick in at the same time) uses *window.innerWidth*

the result is safari getting jumbled by have the css load for the size where it shouldn't for 15 px -

the only fix I can find is writing some safari specific js  - which is not ideal, but the only thing i can think of.

Comment: so I've determined the OSX Safari is using document.documentElement.clientWidth measurements for media queries 
while chrome / firefox are using .innerWidth - hence the 15 pixel gap

Comment: It's all about the scrollbars.

Comment: so do I need to make a secondary css for safari? I have javascript that relies on when the media query is engaged -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.innerWidth` is the width of the viewport, which [includes vertical scrollbars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth).

My guess is the media queries are triggering based on the width of the viewport **minus** the scrollbar, which would account for the 18px discrepancy. This explains it better than I can:

http://www.sitepoint.com/rwd-scrollbars-is-chrome-better/

Comment: So i found the differences 

console.log("inner width: " + window.innerWidth);
console.log("doc client: " + document.documentElement.clientWidth);

chromes media query's follow innerwidth, while safari does the clientwidth.